# and really at the start of a sentence

Tags: sentence-starts

When writing a dialogue , can I say "And really, resilience is all there is, so not to worry to and fro."

Can I start with "And really"
?

Comment: It’s dialogue. You’re writing what your character says. It’s fine.

Comment: @bmils Why would you *not* start with "And really"? People often tack on additional thoughts, and having finished one sentence they need to start another.

Answer (score 0):

*And* is almost always used as a conjunction. It links the following to the previous. Hence you may use it to start a sentence in the context of some previous thought.

*Really* suggests a comparison of perception with a reality.

And really, my answer is just words on a screen.